# UART adapter to... what is this connector's name?

Tags: connector, uart, adapter, identification

Any idea of what the connector from the right is named?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's a board to board connector. Can you use a scope to identify any markings? Other useful information would be the connector dimensions and pitch.

Comment: Do you have a better picture of the right hand one?

Comment: What's the left one doing there? You only ask about the other one.

Comment: @Oli - I think it's the one in my answer. Better picture.

Comment: @Kortuk - Why was this converted to a comment? It completely answers his question. He asked what type of connector the photo to the right was. It is a board to board connector. I could delete the request for more information on the exact part and it would still be a complete answer eh?

Comment: @Jason - You can take the question literally, and then an answer can be just 1 word. Or you can tell a bit more about it, like I tried in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The left one is called **Micro-MaTch™** connector, and it's a board to flat cable

[image]

or board-to-board connector. This is a two-part connector, but there are also versions where you solder the flat cable holding part directly, so that it can't be removed.

[image]

The other one is a board-to-board connector, like Jason says.

[image]

Usually you'll have a couple of them, so that the boards can't rotate relative to the other one. This is tricky, though, as the least mispositioning will cause strain on the solder connections.

**Further information**
[Micro-MaTch Connectors Overview](http://www.te.com/catalog/minf/en/439) at TE

Comment: What type of board to board connector is that?, I'm bumping into lots of different types and cannot find that specific one.

Comment: @duke - It could be a [JMC connector](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=147) by JST.